# Cannot update Xamarin for Visual Studio

Tags: xamarin, installation, xamarin-studio

I had to re-install my PC recently, and I re-installed VS2015 Community. And then I installed Xamarin from www.xamarin.com/download

I get the following notice whenever I open visual studio

[image]

Although when I click it nothing happens. It just disappears.

Previously on my old version, I had Xamarin Studio, where i could go in, and check for updates, which would also update Xamarin for VS2015. But for the life of me I cannot find a download for Xamarin Studio anymore, I am assuming it got discontinued since Microsoft takeover in order to force use of Visual Studio?

I have downloaded both Xamarin Installer (which also always shows that the VS 2015 Xamarin plugin is missing). But when it goes to install it, it starts some sort of setup/installer which then disappears and it takes me to the Xamarin developers page and shows successful.

I have also tried installing/forcing an update via the "vstoolsforxamarin.exe" VS2015 installer, but no luck. C#/Xamarin is installed and won't update from there :-(.

I can see the XamarinInstaller installs the following version of Xamarin.VisualStudio:

\Temp\Xamarin\downloads\Xamarin.VisualStudio_4.1.1.1.msi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install which you found MSI build in temp folder I hope this latest version or 
Two ways to fix solution 
1.Better goto your Xamarin site login ur account and download the latest version and install 
2. Or goto VS-tools menu- Xamarin - disable checking update

Answer (score 2):

For me it worked this way,

1-) Installed .Net 4.6 Framework
2-) Installed Microsoft MSBuild Tools 2015 downloaded from here https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48159

Then installer worked .. you can get the installer from here,

download.xamarin.com/XamarinforVisualStudio/Windows/Xamarin.VisualStudio_4.1.1.1.msi