# Cannot update Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015, updates

I am trying to update Xamarin in hopes of clearing a [bug](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=42864) related to Http calls. Visual Studio finds the Xamarin update, but when I attempt to run the msi it fails with the following message:

[image: This setup requires Microsot Build Tools 2015 package to be installed]

I use VS 2015 Professional so this should not be an issue. I also saw a Xamarin employee mention that cycle 7 requires Build Tools 2013 to be installed as well ([link](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/69895/help-cant-install-xamarin-visual-studio-4-1-1-1)). I have verified the 2013 build tools are installed on my machine, as it is listed in Programs and Features. I have seen other devs mention this issue on Xamarin forums, and here, but there is not any resolution that I have seen.

After doing more research, some suggested ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38170442/cannot-update-xamarin-for-visual-studio)) downloading the Xamarin installer from Xamarin's website. I did so and it is a different installer, but it also fails.

**Two interesting things about this installer...**

**1)** It pointed me to it's install log where I found these lines:

```
[2016-10-27 12:32:00.737] [Debug] Detecting software item 'Microsoft® MSBuild Tools 2015'
[2016-10-27 12:32:00.738] [Info] Checking whether Microsoft Build Tools 2015.0 are installed
[2016-10-27 12:32:00.739] [Info] Visual Studio 2015 found. Not installing standalone Microsoft Build Tools
[2016-10-27 12:32:00.741] [Info] Status: successful
[2016-10-27 12:32:00.742] [Info] Component 'Microsoft® MSBuild Tools 2015' v. 0.0.0 present
[2016-10-27 12:32:00.744] [Info] Software item 'Microsoft® MSBuild Tools 2015': up to date
[2016-10-27 12:32:00.745] [Info] Detection complete
[2016-10-27 12:32:00.746] [Info] Initial task completed successfully
[2016-10-27 12:32:00.748] [Debug] Detection completed.
```

So clearly I do have Build Tools 2015 installed. I've even tried installing the standalone tools from MS download but the results are the same.

**2)** At the end it suggested I download the same msi that Visual Studio finds. When I download, it fails with the Build Tools message as expected (in the Xamarin section) [image]

Has anyone else encountered this and found a solution, or have suggestions on how I can proceed to update Xamarin?

Answer (score 2):

Open a Command Prompt as an Administrator and run the below two commands (assuming that your current .msi is "CEEB6A85-3EE8-4027-8DDA-747947CA970D-40300609", else substitute with your version of the .msi):

```
cd %LocalAppData%\MonoDevelop-4.0\Cache\TempDownload
msiexec.exe /i CEEB6A85-3EE8-4027-8DDA-747947CA970D-40300609.msi
```

This then breaks Xamarin completely however, and one has to perform a Repair by double clicking the .msi as a normal user and following the prompts.

After that VS 2015 should show that Xamarin has been successfully upgraded.